# Why is "++i++" invalid while (++i)++ is valid?

Tags: c++, operators, lvalue, post-increment, pre-increment

Let's consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    int i = 2;
    int b = ++i++;
    return 3;
}
```

It compiles with the following with an error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:3:16: error: lvalue required as increment operand

    3 |     int b = ++i++;

      |                ^~
```

This sounds fair to me. Postfix increment has higher priority than prefix increment, so the code is parsed as `int b = ++(i++);` and `i` is an rvalue. Hence the error.

Let's now consider this variant with parenthesis to override default priorities:

```
int main() {
    int i = 2;
    int b = (++i)++;
    return 3;
}
```

This code compiles and returns 3. On its own, this sounds fair to me but it seems in contradiction with the first code.

**The question: why `(++i)` is an `lvalue` when `i` is not?**

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** the error message shown above was from gcc (x86-64 9.2). Here is the exact rendering:
[error with gcc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjrhK.png)

Clang x86-64 9.0.0 has a quite different message:
[error with clang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUqAk.png)

```
<source>:3:13: error: expression is not assignable

    int b = ++i++;

            ^ ~~~
```

With GCC, you get the impression that the problem is with the postfix operator and you can then wander why `++i` is OK while `i` is not, hence my question. With Clang it is clearer that the problem is with the prefix operator.

Comment: This was originally tagged with C, it most certainly isn't valid C.

Comment: Indeed sorry! I assumed the behavior was the same in C...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`i` and `++i` are both lvalues, but `i++` is an rvalue.

`++(i++)` cannot be valid, as the prefix `++` is being applied to `i++`, which is an rvalue. But `(++i)++` is fine because `++i` is an lvalue.

Note that in C, the situation is different; `i++` and `++i` are both rvalues. (This is an example of why people should stop assuming that C and C++ have the same rules. People insert these assumptions into their questions, which must then be refuted.)

Answer (score 4):

This declaration

```
int b = ++i++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int b = ++( i++ );
```

The postfix increment operator returns the value of the operand before increment.

From the C++ 17 Standard (8.2.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its
>   operand...**The result is a prvalue**.

While the unary increment operator returns lvalue after its increment. So this declaration

```
int b = (++i)++;
```

is valid. You could for example write

```
int b = (++++++++i)++;
```

From the C++ 17 Standard (8.3.2 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1. The operand shall
>   be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic
>   type other than cv bool, or a pointer to a completely-defined object
>   type. **The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue**, and it is a
>   bit-field if the operand is a bit-field....

Pay attention that in C the both operators return a value instead of lvalue. So in C this declaration

```
int b = (++i)++;
```

is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

> so the code is parsed as int b = ++(i++); and i is an rvalue.

No. `i` is not an rvalue. `i` is an lvalue. `i++` is an rvalue (prvalue to be specific).